# Squeeze Theorem Conditions

Tags: calculus, limits

I am learning about the Squeeze Theorem applied to functions. I want some clarity on two examples:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1}(x-1)^2 \sin{\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)} = 0.$$ However, $$\lim \limits_{x \to 1}(x+1)^2 \sin{\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)} \;\text{ does not exist}.$$

I know that $-1 \leq \sin{\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)} \leq 1$, and that both $(x+1)^2 \geq 0$ and $(x-1)^2 \geq 0$ but I would not the get the same answer if I applied the Squeeze Theorem. Am I missing a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$-1\leq \sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\leq 1,$$ you have $$-(x+1)^2\leq (x+1)^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\leq (x+1)^2,$$ from which all you can conclude is that (if it exists at all!), $$-2\leq \lim_{x \to 1} (x+1)^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\leq 2.$$ But in fact it doesn't exist because it oscillates between $-2$ and 2 as $x \to 1$.  (Consider $x=1+\frac{2}{\pi k}$, where $k$ is an odd integer.)